# What do you have to check before Shabbat enters?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

I know you have to ask your family if certain things have been done, what are these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you are thinking of the mishna in [Shabbos 2 (7)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h21.htm)

> ז] שלושה דברים צריך אדם לומר בתוך ביתו ערב שבת, עם חשיכה--עישרתן,
>   עירבתן, הדליקו את הנר

On erev Shabbos before it gets dark, a man must say three things in his house: "Have you taken tithes. Have you prepared the eruv? Kindle the lamp."

Practically speaking, it might be good to check all the preparations for Shabbos in time so that you can correct any omissions.